# Iterating big array vs multiple arrays vs object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

**Is there any noticeable performance difference between these three scenarios?**

---

**Scenario 1:** two arrays already *sorted* by *condition*

```
//Array 1: 25 000 items
var count = myFirstArray.length;

for( a = 0; a < count; a++ ) {

    //Action 1
}

//Array 2: 25 000 items
var count = mySecondArray.length;

for( a = 0; a < count; a++ ) {

    //Action 2
}
```

---

**Scenario 2:** one big array, check *condition* in loop

```
//Single array: 50 000 items
var count = myArray.length;

for( a = 0; a < count; a++ ) {

    if( /* Condition is met */ ) {

        //Action 1
    }
    else {

        //Action 2
    }
}
```

---

**Scenario 3:** one object that contains two arrays - good for storing other data too

```
//Single object with arrays: each with 25 000 items
var firstCount = myObject['myFirstArray'].length;
var secondCount = myObject['mySecondArray'].length;

for( a = 0; a < firstCount; a++ ) {

    //Action 1
}
for( a = 0; a < secondCount; a++ ) {

    //Action 2
}
```

Comment: Why don't you test it and find out ?

Comment: Branch Prediction will influence the result, I guess

Comment: Obviously the 2nd option is the slowest. 1st and 3rd are basically the same.

Comment: Obvious it is not, at least to the OP. However I agree the second variant is likely to be a bit slower than if the objects are pre-grouped based on the condition (assuming the cost to pre-group is not significant).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it's been mentioned in the comments, Scenario 1 and 3 are essentially the same (with the only difference is that you're obtaining the arrays from an object. Retrieving the array from the object is [constant time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity#Constant_time) so no damage there)